# Best practice for Open ID Connect with mobile client

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'll have an Identify Server as an STS. I'm trying to authenticate/authorize a trusted mobile app. Is Open ID Connect still a viable option ? I'm concerned about the usability (redirecting users to a url) as well as ios/android biometrics.
If Open ID Connect is still an option, what's the recommended flow for this scenario?

Comment: Here is a in-depth breakdown of this topic https://www.pingidentity.com/developer/en/resources/napps-native-app-sso.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AppAuth](https://appauth.io/) is the clear direction if this is referring to a "Native Application" on a mobile device.

"*It follows the best practices set out in [RFC 8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252) - OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps including using in-app browser tabs (like SFAuthenticationSession and Android Custom Tabs) where available. Embedded user-agents (known as web-views) **are explicitly not supported** due to the usability and security reasons documented in Section 8.12 of RFC 8252.*"